# Finding the bounding boxes of different symbols/letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I am learning about OpenCV bounding boxes and so far it has been good to me. However, I am having trouble finding the bounding slightly more complicated letters/symbols.

I have looked at the documentation, but I couldn't find anything relating to how to find bounding boxes of complicated symbols/letters (eg %, ! or the letter j or i)

I have attached my input image.[image: Input Image]

The code I use to process the bounding boxes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgCont=img.copy()
imgFinal=img.copy()


imggray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgcanny=cv2.Canny(imggray,200,240)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(imgcanny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

rect_d=[] #store the dimensions of my bounding boxes
min_cont_area=10
for cnt in contours:
    #print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>min_cont_area: #Limit the contours based on area?  
        box_d=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x,y,w,h=box_d
        rect_d.append([x,y,w,h]) 
        cv2.rectangle(imgCont, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0, 0, 255),1)

i=0
roi_n=[] #store each bounding box for later
for d in range(0,len(rect_d)):    
    x=rect_d[i][0] #Find x 
    y=rect_d[i][1] #Find y 
    w=rect_d[i][2] #Find width 
    h=rect_d[i][3] #Find height 
    roi=imgFinal[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    roi_n.append(roi)
    cv2.imwrite('Boxed_ROIs_'+str(i) + '.jpg', roi) 
    i+=1

cv2.imshow('Final Result',imgCont)
cv2.imwrite('Final Result.jpg',imgCont)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output I get from my code.
[image: My output]

If anyone can help me understand how to go about :

1) Find irregular bounding polygons (not boxes) eg with the "square root of 3" have a irregular bounding polygon for the "square root" and a bounding box for "3"

2) Is it possible to say merge bounding boxes horizontally/vertically/diagonally. Eg it would help if I know how to vertically merge the bounding boxes for the "=" sign or diagonally merge the bounding boxes for "%".

3) Is it also possible to split bounding boxes into several bounding boxes?

My desired output would look something like this.
[image]

**********************UPDATE********************************************

I managed to update based on your suggestions however, I am not sure how to get the square root symbol, ! and = symbol on its own bounding boxes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgCont=img.copy()
imgFinal=img.copy()

imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,imgThresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray,249,250,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel_erosion = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
imgErode = cv2.erode(imgThresh,kernel_erosion,iterations = 2)

kernel_open = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(1,2))
imgOpen = cv2.morphologyEx(imgErode, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_open)

kernel_dilate = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
imgDilate = cv2.dilate(imgOpen,kernel_dilate,iterations = 4)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(imgDilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

rect_d=[] #store the dimensions of my bounding boxes
min_cont_area=5
for cnt in contours:
    #print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>min_cont_area: #Limit the contours based on area?  
        box_d=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x,y,w,h=box_d
        rect_d.append([x,y,w,h]) 
        cv2.rectangle(imgCont, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0, 0, 255),1)

i=0
roi_n=[] #store each bounding box for later
for d in range(0,len(rect_d)):    
    x=rect_d[i][0] #Find x 
    y=rect_d[i][1] #Find y 
    w=rect_d[i][2] #Find width 
    h=rect_d[i][3] #Find height 
    roi=imgFinal[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    roi_n.append(roi)
    cv2.imwrite('Boxed_ROIs_'+str(i) + '.jpg', roi) 
    i+=1

#cv2.imshow('Final Result',imgCont)
#cv2.imwrite('Final Result.jpg',imgCont)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My updated output:
[image: Update Output]

Comment: It seems that you have implemented a minimum area filter with `min_cont_area`, set to 10 px. That's likely the reason you don't get the bounding boxes for some of the characters (e.g. the **W**s). Try lowering the threshold instead. For the cases you are getting multiple bounding boxes for, what you consider one “composite character” (like the fraction) a  possible solution is to “merge” the “child” bounding boxes to a “parent”. This can be done via morphology pre-processing (maybe a vertical `dilation` operation) or contour analyzing (look for “close” centroids between contours).

Comment: @eldesgraciado Yes, I've played around with the `min_cont_area` and it did capture the **W's**. Is there any documentation/theory that I can find on the net? I will give your approach a go with morphology/erosion/dilation. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are trying to filter out noise, consider implementing first (before bounding box detection) a pre-processing stage. The goal of such stage is just to filter out noise (like small pixels, for example) and preserve the relevant info (the actual characters) that you want to detect. Your image seems clean already (likely because it was made in a graphics editor) so it might not need this stage, however, if your image turned out to be a photo of text on a label, for example, or a scanned document, pre-processing is pretty much needed.

Comment: [Here's](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) a python tutorial on basic morphology.

Comment: Why do you do canny edge detection? Why not just invert the polarity so that the letters are white on black background, convert to gray, threshold. Then find the contours of the characters.